# Acessing image in filesystem in Cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I'm downloading images in the persistent filesystem with Cordova/Phonegap.

I've created the file from a `Blob` using the documented way :

```js
 window.requestFileSystem(window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, callback);
```

Using
`phonegap serve` to test the application, I can see the file by opening a tab in Chrome at `filesystem:http://localhost:3000/persistent/assembly/http%253A%252F%252Fplayground%252Fappcentralsync.rdf%2523i15319183814240222/items/item-1/intro.png`

But within the application I'm not able to load the image from the DOM. I've tried :

```html
<img src="cdvfile:http://localhost/persistent/assembly/http%253A%252F%252Fplayground%252Fappcentralsync.rdf%2523i15319183814240222/items/item-1/intro.png" />
```

I've updated the CSP to add the `cdvfile:` protocol and added the tag `<access  origin="cdvfile://*" />` to statisfy the whitelist plugin.

The request is blocked on the browser and Android with a status code 0.

I'm using the followinfg plugins:

```xml
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
```